# Python: date time in `date '+%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p'` to unixtime

Tags: python, datetime, time

A certain program gives me the output in `'+%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p'` ( 04/Mar/15 5:53 PM) format. I want to convert this to unix time so I could check for the delta between the output and `'date +%s'`. I want to be able to do this in python. Please help.

Comment: You don't need unix time, you can use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Comment: How do I do that? Can you give me an example?